# Store/Secure openssl cert and key file in TPM2.0

Tags: encryption, tls, linux, tpm, raspberry-pi

I have my TPM2.0 connected to my raspberry pi. I generated a Cert file and Private key using openssl. These files are used to connect MQTT with TLS. How do I store/secure these files in/with the TPM on a raspberry pi. Once stored/secured how do I use them again? Say in a command like this:

```
    curl -v \
      -X POST https://<The-domain> \
      --cert ./encrytped-cert.pem \
      --key ./encrypted-key.pem \
      -d temperature=50
```

The end goal is to use these files in an MQTT python script. For now doing it in command line would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which underlying implementation the Python MQTT libs uses, but some MQTT libraries can use a PKCS#11 token to handle crypto operations.

You now need something exposing the TPM chip as PKCS#11 token, e.g. https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-pkcs.

BTW don't import keys on the TPM if you can generate keys on chip.